# Error in link_to in symfony admin generator

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, link-to, admin-generator

I made two List actions. One actually corresponds to the default _new action and other is slightly different. So in generator.yml, I put:

```
  list:    
    max_per_page: 10
    title: All Posters
    display: [approved, name, user_id, _web_path, created_at]
    actions:
      upload : #this is actually equivalent to _new. 
        credentials: create_poster
        label: "Upload Poster"
        action: new
      create : 
        credentials: create_poster
        label: "Create Poster"
```

Now in my list view, I can see two links for these two actions but the create Link links to 
***/poster/ListCreate/action*** instead of ***/poster/ListCreate***. What can be a reason for that? I'm also pasting the _list_actions.php file in the cache.

```
<li class="sf_admin_action_upload">
<?php if ($sf_user->hasCredential('create_poster')): ?>
<?php echo link_to(__('Upload Poster', array(), 'messages'), 'poster/new', array()) ?>
<?php endif; ?>

</li>
<li class="sf_admin_action_create">
  <?php if ($sf_user->hasCredential('create_poster')): ?>
<?php echo link_to(__('Create Poster', array(), 'messages'), 'poster/create', array()) ?>
<?php endif; ?>

</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a custom action:

```
list:
  actions:    
    myaction: 
      label: "My action"
      action: myaction
```

you have to write a routing rule to have the behavior you are looking for:

```
myaction:
  url:   /mymodule/myaction
  param: { module: mymodule, action: myaction }
```

Comment: thanks. And that rule has to be above sfDoctrineRouteCollection.

Comment: You're welcome. I forgot to write that I use `Propel`, so if there are differences the rule must be translated for `Doctrine`.

Comment: .. and yes, the rule has to be wrote above the general rule of the module because routing rules are read from the top to the bottom.